# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when fetching

Tags: reactjs, node.js, connection

I am trying to build a DALL-E clone project (image generator). This is a JSM tutorial and I have seen 2 or 3 questions about the same project here but none of them could help me.
So I am using reactjs, nodejs and mongodb and I am trying to connect the front-end with the backend but i keep getting this error on chrome:

CreatePost.jsx:22
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dalle net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

and this error on firefox:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dalle. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
Even though I could get the message on the server side.

This is my CreatePost.js file (front-end side):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

import { preview } from '../assets'
import { getRandomPrompt } from '../utils'
import { FormField, Loader } from '../components'

const CreatePost = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name :'',
    prompt:'',
    photo:''
  })
  const [generatingImg, setGeneratingImg] = useState(false)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const generateImage = async() =>{
    if(form.prompt){
      try {
        setGeneratingImg(true);
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dalle', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({prompt: form.prompt})
        })

        const data = await response.json();
        setForm({ ...form, photo: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${data.photo}` });
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error)
      }finally{
        setGeneratingImg(false)
      }
    } else{
      alert('Please enter a prompt')
    }
  }

  const handleSubmit = () => {

  }

  const handleChange = (e) => setForm({ ...form, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const handleSurpriseMe = () => {
    const randomPrompt = getRandomPrompt(form.prompt);
    setForm({ ...form, prompt: randomPrompt });
  };

  return (
    <section className='max-w-7xl mx-auto'>
      <div>
        <h1 className='font-extrabold text-[#222328] text-[32px]'>Create</h1>
        <p className='mt-2 text-[#666e75] text-[16px] max-w[500px]'>
          Create imaginative and visually stunning images through DALL-E AI and share them with the community
        </p>
      </div>

      <form className='mt-16 max-w-3xl' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className='flex flex-col gap-5'>
          <FormField
            labelName="Your Name"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Ex., john doe"
            value={form.name}
            handleChange={handleChange}
          />

          <FormField
            labelName="Prompt"
            type="text"
            name="prompt"
            placeholder="A plush toy robot sitting against a yellow wall"
            value={form.prompt}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            isSurpriseMe
            handleSurpriseMe={handleSurpriseMe}
          />

          <div
            className='relative bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg
            focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 w-64 p-3 h-64 flex justify-center items-center'>
            {form.photo ? (
              <img
                src={form.photo}
                alt={form.prompt} 
                className='w-full h-full object-contain'
              />
            ):
            (
              <img
                src={preview}
                alt={preview}
                className='w-9/12 h-9/12 object-contain opacity-40'
              />
            )}

            {generatingImg && (
              <div className='absolute inset-0 z-0 flex justify-center items-center bg-[rgb(0,0,0,0.5)] rounded-lg'>
                <Loader/>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='mt-5 flex gap-5'>
          <button
            type='button'
            onClick={generateImage}
            className='text-white bg-green-700 font-medium rounded-md text-sm w-full sm:w-auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center hover:opacity-90'
          >
            {generatingImg ? 'Generating...' : 'Generate' }
          </button>
        </div>

        <div className='mt-10'>
          <p className='mt-2 text-[#666e75] text-[14px]'>
            Once you have created the image you want, you can share it with others in the community
          </p>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className='mt-3 text-white bg-[#6469ff] font-medium rounded-md text-sm w-full sm:w-auto 
            px-5 py-2.5 text-center hover:opacity-90'
          >
            {loading ? 'sharing...' : 'Share with the community'}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  )
}

export default CreatePost
```

the configuration code:

```js
import express from 'express'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import cors from 'cors'

import connectDB from './mongodb/connect.js'
import postRoutes from './routes/postRoutes.js'
import dalleRoutes from './routes/dalleRoutes.js'

dotenv.config()

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }))

app.use('/api/v1/post', postRoutes)
app.use('/api/v1/dalle', dalleRoutes)

app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello from DALL-E')
})

const startServer = async() => {

    try {
        connectDB(process.env.MONGODB_URL)
        app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server has started on port 8080'))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

}

startServer()
```

and Server Side
dalleRoutes:

```js
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { OpenAI } from 'openai'


dotenv.config()

const router = express.Router()


const openai = new OpenAI({
    apikey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
})
// const openai = new OpenAI(config)


router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello from DALL-E!' });
  });
  
router.route('/').post(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { prompt } = req.body
        const aiResponse = await openai.images.generate({
            prompt,
            n: 1,
            size: "1024x1024",
            response_format: "b64_json",
        });
        const image = aiResponse.data[0].b64_json;
        res.status(200).json({ photo:image })
            
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).send(error?.response.data.error.message || 'Something went wrong')
    }
})

export default router
```